# Auto load specific documents based on initial document (page 1) information in javascript for Adobe Acrobat DC

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I apologize in advance if my explanation of this problem/issue is confusing.

I'm putting together a packet of documents for field technicians to get filled out/signed in the field while they're on the job site.  I can handle that part.

My issue currently is I was tasked to figure out a way to have only certain documents load based on the first page the technician fills out on the job site (called: Initial Job Diary)

The need for this is the work that we do is for Insurance Companies, and well they all want different paperwork done for similar condition jobs.  So the tech would fill out his "Initial Job Diary" and he finds out from the customer that they have XYZ Insurance Company - once XYZ Insurance Company was selected on the Initial Job Diary, the required forms for XYZ Insurance Company is auto populated for him to get filled out/signed.

I can try to explain in further detail if needed.  Any/All help is deeply appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What PDF viewer will the field technicians be using and what OS? What you want can be doen if using Acrobat on Windows or OS X, and becomes more difficult with Adobe Reader on Windows or OSX, and impossible on iOS/Android.

It's also important to know what type of signature is required. Options include digital signature, e-signature via a service like Adobe Sign or DocuSign, or a mere scribble annotation.